# Android Image Getter for Larger Images

Tags: android, thumbnails

I have used all the Standard Network related code for Getting Images of about `45KB to 75KB` but all are failing these methods work fine for Files of about `3-5KB` size of Images. How can I achieve Downloading Image of `45 - 75KB` for displaying them on an ImageView in Android for my Network Operations the Things I have used are

```
final URL url = new URL(urlString);

final URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;

httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(true);

httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");

httpConn.connect();
```

and the Second option that I have had used is::

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(urlString);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
```

why is this code functional for Smaller Sized Images and not for Larger Size Images. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice to see what kind of code you use for decoding the response into a bitmap. Anyway, try using a BufferedInputStream like this:

```
public Bitmap getRemoteImage(final URL aURL) { 
  try { 
    final URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection(); 
    conn.connect(); 
    final BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream()); 
    final Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis); 
    return bm; 
  } catch (IOException e) { 
    Log.d("DEBUGTAG", "Oh noooz an error..."); 
  } 
  return null; 
}
```

Comment: Ya PHP_Jedi BufferedInputStream is really what i thought of this is really something that would solve the problem and yes thanks for helping man.

Answer (score 7):

The size of the image you are downloading is pretty irrelevant. The size it decodes with BitmapFactory.decodeStream, however is the memory you are going to need to handle the image.
Therefore a reSampling might be useful.

```
    Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

    Boolean scaleByHeight = Math.abs(options.outHeight - TARGET_HEIGHT) >= Math.abs(options.outWidth - TARGET_WIDTH);

    if(options.outHeight * options.outWidth >= 200*200){
    // Load, scaling to smallest power of 2 if dimensions >= desired dimensions
    double sampleSize = scaleByHeight
            ? options.outHeight / TARGET_HEIGHT
            : options.outWidth / TARGET_WIDTH;
    options.inSampleSize = 
          (int)Math.pow(2d, Math.floor(
          Math.log(sampleSize)/Math.log(2d)));
    }

    // Do the actual decoding
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    is.close();
    is = getHTTPConnectionInputStream(sUrl);
    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
    is.close();
```

Comment: Robert Foss the size i'm talking here is not a the image bounded size but the size of the image on the server  and the issue is that while downloading the image of 40K the download becomes unsuccessful and unfruitful. anything below that the same code suffices the matter. that is what is my issue is.

Comment: Hi Robert!
What the " 200*200*2" mean?

Comment: It was a while since I wrote this. 200*200 is the largest size allowed for the picture before it will do any resizing.


options.outHeight * options.outWidth * 2 >= 200*200*2
Should be changed into:
    options.outHeight * options.outWidth >= 200*200

Dont know how that extra *2 snuck its way there :P
Removed it in the soulution.

Comment: Your reply may not be the right one for the question, but it sure was right for my out of memory errors :) Cheers